# Retrieving every dependencies with Karaf Maven Plugin and create Karaf Archive

Tags: osgi, dependency-management, apache-karaf, karaf, apache-servicemix

I'm using ServiceMix 6.1.0 (containing Karaf 3.0.5) and I have a Maven project. I want to create a Karaf Archive (.kar) using `karaf-maven-plugin`.

I understood the goal of using a Karaf Archive : retrieving every dependencies so that the .kar can be deployed in an offline environment. Well... I thought I had understood... After creating .kar and deploying it, I get an error :

```
Error executing command: Can't install feature karafMavenPlugin/0.0.0:
Could not start bundle mvn:org.testng/testng/6.8.8 in feature(s) karafMavenPlugin-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: 
Unresolved constraint in bundle org.testng [371]: 
Unable to resolve 371.0: 
missing requirement [371.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=org.junit)
```

Here is the `pom.xml` :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>test</groupId>
  <artifactId>karafMavenPlugin</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>kar</packaging>
  <name>TestKarafMavenPlugin</name>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Plugin to create .kar -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.karaf.tooling</groupId>
                <artifactId>karaf-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.5</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <aggregateFeatures>true</aggregateFeatures>
                    <includeTransitiveDependency>true</includeTransitiveDependency>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings 
                    only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>
                                            org.apache.karaf.tooling
                                        </groupId>
                                        <artifactId>
                                            karaf-maven-plugin
                                        </artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>
                                            [3.0.5,)
                                        </versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>
                                                features-generate-descriptor
                                            </goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore></ignore>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.8.8</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Here is the `feature.xml` generated :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<features xmlns="http://karaf.apache.org/xmlns/features/v1.2.1" name="karafMavenPlugin">
    <feature name="karafMavenPlugin" version="0.0.1-SNAPSHOT" description="TestKarafMavenPlugin">
        <bundle>mvn:org.testng/testng/6.8.8</bundle>
        <bundle>wrap:mvn:org.beanshell/bsh/2.0b4</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:com.beust/jcommander/1.27</bundle>
    </feature>
</features>
```

**Why is the JUnit dependency not retrieved ?**

My guess would be that `karaf-maven-plugin` does not retrieve dependencies in `pom.xml` which are `<optional>` or `<provided>`. Indeed, JUnit is a TestNG's dependency and here is the TestNG's `pom.xml` (only dependencies) :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
  <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <name>TestNG</name>
  <version>6.8.8</version>
  <description>TestNG is a testing framework.</description>
  <url>http://testng.org</url>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
      <artifactId>ant</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.0</version>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.10</version>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.beanshell</groupId>
      <artifactId>bsh</artifactId>
      <version>2.0b4</version>
<!--
      <scope>provided</scope>
-->
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
      <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
      <version>2.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.beust</groupId>
      <artifactId>jcommander</artifactId>
      <version>1.27</version>
    </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
        <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
        <version>1.12</version>
      <optional>true</optional>
      </dependency>
  </dependencies>    
</project>
```

We can see that every dependencies who are not `<optional>` and not `<provided>` are retrieved by `karaf-maven-plugin`.

So... Am I wrong ? Is it an expected behavior ? If it is the case, is there a way to indicate to the `karaf-maven-plugin` to download **every** dependencies ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in the maven documentation about [scope](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope) :

> **provided**
>
> This is much like compile, but indicates you expect the JDK or a container to provide the dependency at runtime. For example,
>   when building a web application for the Java Enterprise Edition, you
>   would set the dependency on the Servlet API and related Java EE APIs
>   to scope provided because the web container provides those classes.
>   This scope is only available on the compilation and test classpath,
>   and is not transitive.

'provided' is not transitive : when asking for maven dependencies through api, the provided dependencies are not retrieved.

So, in order to work with karaf-maven-plugin, you have to explicitly add this dependency in the pom.